# Retrieving data from Facebook graph API using F#

Tags: facebook-graph-api, f#, c#-to-f#

I have been using C# with the [Newtonsoft.Json](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) library to collect data from Facebook. This is working reasonably well for me, but now I would like to see if I can do something similar with F# instead of C#.

I note that F# 3.0 (now in beta) has support for [type providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which have the potential to make access to loosely structured data like Facebook much easier.

Does anyone know of an F# sample showing how to get Facebook data?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned type providers: [FSharpx](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx) has a JSON type provider, but I think it currently works with local files only, not with a JSON fetched from a HTTP request. You're welcome to [join the project](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/fsharpx) and help us with this!